# SQL Injection safe with encryption?

Tags: php, encryption, code-injection

I've heard a lot about SQL injection and also read a lot of good answers in other topics.
So I want to make sure I'm not vulnerable.
What if I encrypt all user input (wanted to do that anyway - using openssl) before inserting it into my mysql database?

Wouldn't it be an easy and safe way for a beginner to avoid sql injection?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend encrypting everything just sensitive data.  To prevent SQL Injection it is far more effective using proper request and input validation along with proper escape sequences and save yourself the headache of your application performance being hindered with every database transaction. Most of the time when you want to prevent prying eyes you use 1 way encryption on things such as a password.  But if you are saving things such as credit cards and such its wise to follow the standardized security for credit card encryption.  Encryption is good but over using it can cause far more problems than it saved you from.  So think about what data is important and should be encrypted and then consider if it should be 1 way encryption or 2 way.  But the most importantly is validation and never trusting the user input or the application request.

Answer (score -1):

Please use

1. [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/introduction/)
2. Write Stored Procedures in order tot encapsulate your TSQL query
3. SET DEFINE OFF will stop to prevent hackers use & for injection
4. Try to define parameters for queries like SqlCommand()
5. For know more about avoiding injection please read [SQL Injection Prevention](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)